# Replace consecutive characters with same single character

Tags: c#

I was just wondering if there is a simple way of doing this. i.e. Replacing the occurrence of consecutive characters with the same character.

For eg: - if my string is "something likeeeee tttthhiiissss" then my final output should be "something like this".

The string can contain special characters too including space.

Can you guys suggest some simple way for doing this.

Comment: What about situations where words normally have consecutive instances of the same letter?  For example:  bee, beer, beet, meeting, moon, soon ...

Comment: Then those words would turn into be, ber, bet, meting, mon, and son.

Comment: @mquander - I know that.  I was hoping to prompt the OP into thinking a bit more about a doing something like.

Comment: @Mike Chess - yes, its pretty good question. But then it will really get complex to identify such words and ignore them in regex or stringbuilder. Instead I will live with the output I get by replacing consecutive letters by single letter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var regex = new Regex("(.)\\1+");
var str = "something likeeeee!! tttthhiiissss";

Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str, "$1")); // something like! this
```

The regex will match any character `(.)` and `\\1+` will match whatever was captured in the first group.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This mostly worked for me, but I ended up using it in a single line and having to set the regex pattern as a constant using the @ symbol, which required removing one of the backslashes. I was only looking for sequential hyphens, so mine looked more like this:
`str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\-)\1+", "$1");`

Comment: @dadwithkids I haven't compared the performance but a more "common" regex would be write `-{2,}`.

Comment: @dadwithkids your comment really helped me out, was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

```
string myString = "something likeeeee tttthhiiissss";

char prevChar = '';
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char chr in myString)
{
    if (chr != prevChar) {
        sb.Append(chr);
        prevChar = chr;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MStodd: yes. Thanks for noticing that. My answer has been edited.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
s = new string(s
     .Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
     .Where(x => x.i == s.Length - 1 || s[x.i + 1] != x.x)
     .Select(x => x.x)
     .ToArray());
```

In english, we are creating a new string based on a char[] array.  We construct that char[] array by applying a few LINQ operators:

1. `Select`:  Capture the index `i` along with the current character `x`.
2. Filter out charaters that are not the same as the subsequent character
3. Select the character `x.x` back out of the anonymous type `x`.
4. Convert back to a char[] array so we can pass to constructor of `string`.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but can you explain this in a bit more detail? I did not understand.

Comment: This is a LINQ query. I would not recommend using this to do what you are trying to do. It might work but looking at it you really have no idea what the intent of the code is.

Comment: @Dismissile, *you* might have no idea what the intent of the code is, but that's pretty subjective and I totally disagree.

Comment: It's not a subjective judgment to say that this is ugly and hard to read compared to the `foreach`, largely because of the author's poor naming choices (`x.x`? really?)  If you wanted to write it functionally, it would be much clearer to implement a `PartitionBy` in C# which returns a sequence split according to a predicate, or to write a recursive version yourself (which is all of three lines.)

Comment: Most people would have no idea what the intent of this code is. It is subjective but it's a hell of a lot more complex than the regex sample and even the stringbuilder sample.

Comment: This should be the answer, is way more efficiently than that one marked.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter any string");
        string str1, result="", str = Console.ReadLine();
        char [] array= str.ToCharArray();
        int i=0;
        for (i = 0; i < str.Length;i++ )
        {
          if ((i != (str.Length - 1)))
          { if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) 
            {
                str1 = str.Trim(array[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                result += array[i];
            }
          }
          else
          {
          result += array[i];
          }                    
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In this code the program ;

1. will read the string as entered from user

2.Convert the string in char Array using *string.ToChar()*

3. The loop will run for each character in string
4. each character stored in that particular position in array will be compared to the character stored in position one greater than that . And if the characters are found same the character stored in that particular array would be trimmed using *.ToTrim()*
5. For last character the loop will show error of index out of bound as it would be the last position value of the array. That's why I used * if ((i != (str.Length - 1)))*

6.The characters left after trimming are stored in result in concatenated form .

Comment: @MikaS Thank You...Done :)

Answer (score -2):

word = "something likeeeee tttthhiiissss"
re.sub(r"(.)\1+", r"\1",word)

Comment: Please provide valid C# code and explanation, why your suggested solution might help the OP.