# How to replace multiple same type of characters i.e.("lala,,,,lala") to a singular ("lala,lala")

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm trying to build a sentence which I'll use in SQL.
Since where could be human errors and people putting more than one ',' in a sentence i wanted to as if there's a possibility to replace many same characters only into a singular one 
I.E.

```
string text = "lala,,,lala,,,,sdad,,,,123,,,,asd,,"
```

to turn it into

```
"lala,lala,sdad,123,asd"
```

?

Comment: text.Replace(",,", ",").Trim(",")?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace consecutive characters with same single character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971412/replace-consecutive-characters-with-same-single-character)

Comment: `could be human errors and people putting more than one ',' in a sentence` - and people putting [something more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683) in that sentence.

Comment: i've already made adjustments of changing other symbols to ',' thats why i would need to replace them to singular

Comment: Actually, more precise would be a Possible duplicate of [Regex to remove multiple consecutive commas and replace with single comma](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46119102/11683)

Comment: @kriss yeah i could replace it like that using a cycle but i was thinking maybe theres a different way with ome kind of Regex or smthng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
string text = "lala,,,lala,,,,sdad,,,,123,,,,asd,,";
text = string.Join(",", text.Split(',').Where(s => s != ""));
```

Comment: Of all possible ways to solve this problem, this one has to be one of the absolute worst. Not only it unnecessarily uses `Split` and `Join`, it even fails to benefit from [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.8) while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string text = "lala,,,lala,,,,sdad,,,,123,,,,asd,,";

string result = Regex.Replace(text, ",+", ",").TrimEnd(new char[]{','});
```